# WCF CustomBing exception - AddressingNone does not support adding WS-Addressing headers

Tags: c#, wcf, custom-binding

I keep getting the following exception when I use my pragmatically created CustomBinding.

**Addressing Version 'AddressingNone (http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none)' does not support adding WS-Addressing headers.**

Is there any way to resolve this issue?

```
private static CustomBinding CreateCustomBinding(bool useHttps)
{
    BindingElement security;
    BindingElement transport;
    if (useHttps)
    {
        security = SecurityBindingElement.CreateSecureConversationBindingElement(
            SecurityBindingElement.CreateUserNameOverTransportBindingElement());
        transport = new HttpsTransportBindingElement
        {
            MaxBufferPoolSize = 2147483647,
            MaxBufferSize = 2147483647,
            MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647,
        };
    }
    else
    {
        security = SecurityBindingElement.CreateSecureConversationBindingElement(
            SecurityBindingElement.CreateUserNameForSslBindingElement(true));
        transport = new HttpTransportBindingElement
        {
            MaxBufferPoolSize = 2147483647,
            MaxBufferSize = 2147483647,
            MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647,
        };
    }


    var encoding = new MtomMessageEncodingBindingElement
    {
        MaxReadPoolSize = 64,
        MaxWritePoolSize = 16,
        MaxBufferSize = 2147483647,
        MessageVersion = MessageVersion.Soap11,
        WriteEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
    };

    //var encoding = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement();


    var customBinding = new CustomBinding();

    customBinding.Elements.Add(security);
    customBinding.Elements.Add(encoding);
    customBinding.Elements.Add(transport);

    return customBinding;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using secure conversation? Is it working when you remove it?

Comment: @LadislavMrnka no it doesn't work either when I remove it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just in case anyone is interested, below is my solution. I added an `if` for dealing with the text encoding section and also updated the `SecurityBindingElement` under `if (useHttps)`:

```
private static CustomBinding CreateCustomBinding(bool useHttps, bool textEncoding)
{
    BindingElement security;
    BindingElement encoding;
    BindingElement transport;
    if (useHttps)
    {
        var seq = SecurityBindingElement.CreateUserNameOverTransportBindingElement();
        seq.MessageSecurityVersion =
            MessageSecurityVersion.
                WSSecurity11WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10;
        seq.SecurityHeaderLayout = SecurityHeaderLayout.Lax;
        seq.DefaultAlgorithmSuite = SecurityAlgorithmSuite.Default;

        security = seq;
        transport = new HttpsTransportBindingElement
        {
            MaxBufferPoolSize = 2147483647,
            MaxBufferSize = 2147483647,
            MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647,
        };
    }
    else
    {
        security = SecurityBindingElement.CreateUserNameOverTransportBindingElement();
        transport = new HttpTransportBindingElement
        {
            MaxBufferPoolSize = 2147483647,
            MaxBufferSize = 2147483647,
            MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647,
        };
    }

    if (textEncoding)
        encoding = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement
        {
            MaxReadPoolSize = 64,
            MaxWritePoolSize = 16,
            MessageVersion = MessageVersion.Soap11,
            WriteEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
        };
    else
        encoding = new MtomMessageEncodingBindingElement
        {
            MaxReadPoolSize = 64,
            MaxWritePoolSize = 16,
            MaxBufferSize = 2147483647,
            MessageVersion = MessageVersion.Soap11,
            WriteEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
        };

    var customBinding = new CustomBinding();

    customBinding.Elements.Add(security);
    customBinding.Elements.Add(encoding);
    customBinding.Elements.Add(transport);

    return customBinding;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me with small changes. Thanks Tawani. Just I set AuthenticationSheme to Basic for HTTPSTransportBinidingElement.

```
transport = new HttpsTransportBindingElement
            {
                MaxBufferPoolSize = 2147483647,
                MaxBufferSize = 2147483647,
                MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647,
                AuthenticationScheme = System.Net.AuthenticationSchemes.Basic
            };
```